# Check whether a geographic-GPS point on a map (lat,lon) is inside a defined rectangle

Tags: c#, coordinates, point, rectangles

I have defined a rectangle on a map with **4 nodes**.

Each one of the nodes is a pair **(X,Y)**

**X:** latitude

**Y:** longitude

**X,Y**:geographic coordinates (with double values)

I would like to check if a **point** **(X,Y)** is **inside that rectangle.**

That point is going to be the current position of the user
(The current position comes from the GPS output of the mobile)

Is there a specific mathematic formula for that?
How can I find if a specific point belongs to a rectangle?

Cause I would like to implement it in C#.

Comment: Are there any restrictions for that rectangle? Are its sides always parallel to the axises?

Comment: Hi, no the sides are not always parallel to the axises. So I got a problem here.

Comment: So, I need something more general, maybe for a polygon with 4 nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rectangle's sides were not parallel to X and Y axis,
I thought that it was better to look for the PIP (Point in Polygon) problem,
something more general that a rectangle.

So, I tested the code in the following post and it seemed to work
for polygon with geo WGS84 coordinates.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739297/805660

thanks for your previous answers

Answer (score 7):

According to this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx

The longitude can range from `-180.0` to `180.0`; so you *have to be accurate* with `-180/180` since `-180` logitude ***is equal to*** `180` one; just imagine a rectangle

```
  (15, 178, 25, -178)
```

the point `(20, 179)` should be within the rectangle and `(20, 177)` should be not; that's why `RectangleF.Contains()` could be incorrect in some cases;

```
// Just to show the idea with 180 latitude;
// First 4 parameters could be crammed into RectangleF
// And last 2 parameters into PointF
public static Boolean WithinRectangle(Double latitudeNorth,
                                      Double longitudeWest,  
                                      Double latitudeSouth,
                                      Double longitudeEast,
                                      Double latitude,
                                      Double longitude) {
  if (latitude > latitudeNorth)
    return false;
  else if (latitude < latitudeSouth)
    return false;

  if (longitudeEast >= longitudeWest)
    return ((longitude >= longitudeWest) && (longitude <= longitudeEast))
  else
    return (longitude >= longitudeWest) || (longitude <= longitudeEast);

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Does your code work with rectangles that their sides are not parallel to the axis X and Y?

Comment: @programmer: No, it doesn't. Rectanle's sides should be latitudes and longitudes

Answer (score 4):

You can create [Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure for those 4 points and then use [Rectangle.Contains Method (Point)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if the point exist in the Rectangle.

For floating point use [RectangleF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its [RectangleF.Contains Method (PointF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9yc2d90%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I would also suggest you to look at [SharpMap](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap) which is an open source project for GIS applications. This has classes like Point, Line, Polygon, BoundingBox etc, and all of them have methods like Intersect, GetBoundingBox, ToWKT, etc. They are really useful for spatial projects.

Comment: Does this function work with geographic coordinates?Cause, I have double values.

Comment: Its basically the same but I would recommend `RectangleF`. Depending on the coordinate system in use the floating point part of the number could be critical.

Comment: I'm using Unity3d, so I guess I'll have to draw a rectangle on the map and use the Contains method afterwards

Comment: @programmer, for that use [`RectangaleF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @programmer, you don't have to draw the rectangle, you can just create it in memory and then check for contains.

Comment: Well I used the Rect method of UnityEngine namespace instead of the .net RectangleF method. I noticed that when the sides are not parallel to the axis X and Y, the Contains method doesn't return the right output (true or false). It returns true even if the point is not inside the rectangle. So what shall I do? Shall I use a method for polygon with 4 nodes?

Comment: What if the rectangle is across the prime meridian? Wouldn't creating a simple rectangle using those points make it wrap the other way around the globe?