# C# implementation of google maps google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I want to check a location is within an area in c# but the google library is only available in javascript
sample code

```
var triangleCoords = [
{lat: 13.1356661, lng: 77.4975465},
{lat: 13.1156035, lng: 77.4082768},
{lat: 13.0085758, lng: 77.3808094},
{lat: 12.8713722, lng: 77.3931875},
{lat: 12.8385751, lng: 77.4714526},
{lat: 12.6805186, lng: 77.7337679},
{lat: 12.7247306, lng: 77.9260408},
{lat: 12.8050967, lng: 77.9411481},
{lat: 12.9416603, lng: 77.8683592},
{lat: 13.0848379, lng: 77.8532521},
{lat: 13.2413016, lng: 77.7887033},
{lat: 13.3001168, lng: 77.7351415},
{lat: 13.2680376, lng: 77.6774595},
{lat: 13.159739, lng: 77.5662156},
{lat: 13.1356661, lng: 77.4975465}
  ];
    var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#00ff00',
    fillOpacity: 0
  });


  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    var resultColor =
        google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle) ?
        'black' :
        'green';

    if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle)) {
      alert('inside the city');
    }
```

[Link to working Sample](https://codepen.io/kundan/pen/rjrveN)

I am not interested in loading the map i just want to be able to do the check

Comment: how did you solved the above?

Answer (score 1):

[`NetTopologySuite` library](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) could be utilized for that matter, here is an example how to determine whether a given point in polygon:

```
var triangleCoords = new[] {
      new Coordinate(25.774, -80.19),
      new Coordinate(18.466, -66.118),
      new Coordinate(32.321, -64.757),
      new Coordinate(25.774, -80.19)
};
IGeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
var poly = geometryFactory.CreatePolygon(triangleCoords);


var locator = new NetTopologySuite.Algorithm.Locate.IndexedPointInAreaLocator(poly);
var location = locator.Locate(new Coordinate(24.886, -70.269));
if (location == GeoAPI.Geometries.Location.Interior)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Polygon contains the location");
}
```

If you prefer no dependency to another libraries, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739297/1375553) contains C# implementation of [Ray casting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) which is commonly used for finding whether the point is inside or outside a polygon.